# How to manage the flowing animation with text wrap (CSS)

Tags: css, animation

I was working on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wb28eeh2/260/

When I try to put a wrapper around the flowing images `<img>` inside `<div>` 
I cannot get any width of the element. Was trying out something like :

[image]

The images occupies the space regardless.What changes can I make to add the text along with the image?

Comment: an easy way would be to use pseudo-elements and and data- attributes for the text

Comment: @FacundoCorradini basically I had problem displaying the text within the required space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues there... First, text is not displaying because you set `font-size:0` on your `.photobanner` classes (probably as a hack for display: inline-block... which you ended up not really using) and totally forgot to reset it in the `.photobanner span`

Just making this change displays the text

```
.photobanner span {
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wb28eeh2/266/

Going further, I think you should reconsider how to make the animation and how to structure your html. Your getting quite a mess of default display modes there.